# Comparing Strings in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am running into what must be a HUGE misunderstanding...

I have an object with a string component ID, I am trying to compare this ID to a string in my code in the following way...

```
if(object.ID == "8jh0086s)
{
//Execute code
}
```

However, when debugging, I can see that ID is in fact "8jh0086s" but the code is not being executed. I have also tried the following

```
if(String.Compare(object.ID,"8jh0086s")==0)
{
//Execute code
}
```

as well as

```
if(object.ID.Equals("8jh0086s"))
{
//Execute code
}
```

And I still get nothing...however I do notice that when I am debugging the '0' in the string object.ID does not have a line through it, like the one in the compare string. But I don't know if that is affecting anything. It is not the letter 'o' or 'O', it's a zero but without a line through it.

Any ideas??

Comment: Yes, your string are not actually identical, and that's why they are compared as different: *string object.ID does not have a line through it, like the one in the compare string.*

Comment: Ok...any thoughts on how this can be remedied?

Comment: What is the type of the property/variable ID of in the object?

Comment: You want non-equal string to be treated as equal?

Comment: Are you talking about `Ø`?

Comment: Try printing the `object.ID` and the string you are comparing it to. Check they are really the same. 0 is not O.

Comment: When I print them using a MessageBox they appear identical

Comment: When you debug, maybe inspect each `char` value in the string, for example watch `(ushort)@object.ID[3]`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter He says that it is not big O

Comment: Try using `str.Select(c => (int)c).ToArray()` or [`Encoding.Default.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx) to see what characters are actually present in the string.

Comment: Copy-past them into `"[paste here]".Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X4")` and compare the results. (LinqPad is good for these little quick things).

Comment: Just to check every possibility try with `if(object.ID.Trim() == "8jh0086s")`

Comment: How can I compare the results..what does that command to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there's something not easily apparent in one of your strings, like a non-printable character for example.

Trying running both strings through this to look at their actual byte values. Both arrays should contain the same numerical values.

```
var test1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(object.ID);
var test2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("8jh0086s");
```

==== Update from first comment ====

A very easy way to do this is to use the ***immediate window*** or ***watch statements*** to execute those statements and view the results without having to modify your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example should be correct.
My guess is there is an un-rendered character present in the Object.ID.

You can inspect this further by debugging, copying both values into an editor like Notepad++ and turning on view all symbols.

Comment: `string` instances can't have different encodings; they're always UTF-16 internally.

Comment: Oh ok, I was thinking of when a Unicode BOM is present/not present, i have personally ran into that issue before.

Comment: There are certainly differences that can exist in strings that should be equivalent (BOM should never make it into a string being used in memory, but that doesn't mean it never happens), they could be different normalisation forms, or be confusables (Т looks a bit like T for example). I'm guessing on a variant of the last. You've the right general idea though, IMO, you just picked the one factor that it's not likely to be in how you phrased it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Jon, I've removed that statement from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you answered  your own question.  If one string has O and the other has 0, then they will compare differently.  I have been in similar situations where strings *seem* the same but they really aren't.  Worst-case, write a loop to compare each individual character one at a time and you might find some subtle difference like that.

Alternatively, if object.ID is not a string, but perhaps something of type "object" then look at this:
http://blog.coverity.com/2014/01/13/inconsistent-equality

The example uses int, not string, but it can give you an idea of the complications with == when dealing with different objects.  But I suspect this is not your problem since you explicitly called String.Compare.  That was the right thing to do, and it tells you that the strings really are different!

Comment: object ID is a string, thanks for your suggestion I will try that.